# How To Build A Special Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to build a special sequence of positive integers such that the product of any two terms is not a perfect square and also to prove the fact of coprimality of any two terms is not needed.For example the terms of Fermat's numbers are pairwise coprime and using this fact we can prove that the product of any two Fermat's numbers is not a perfect square.So this will not work.So please give me some idea or hint.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ to make it clear. I don't understand "to prove it only the structure of the product is enough". I don't understand why the Fermat numbers "don't work".

Comment: @EthanBolker can you prove that the product of two Fermat numbers is not a perfect Square without using the pairwise coprimality of Fermat numbers?

Comment: @EthanBolker I meant here to avoid the use of coprimality in proving this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want. Let $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n p_n$ where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime. For any $i < j$, we have $\gcd(a_i,a_j) = a_i \ne 1$. i.e none of the $(a_i,a_j)$ pairs are co-prime and yet the exponent of $p_j$ in $a_ia_j$ is odd and hence the product $a_ia_j$ cannot be a prefect square. Is such a sequence $a_n$ what you want???

Comment: @achillehui I want a sequence for which we can prove it without using the fact of pairwise coprimality or any analysis of exponents of Primes.

Comment: I want to avoid this use of prime numbers

Comment: @EthanBolker did you get some idea?

Comment: @EthanBolker yes if we can never get the n+1 th term the we can show that the harmonic sum is finite a contradiction and hence we can choose an n+1 th term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build such a sequence recursively. Start with $1,2$. If you've chosen $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ then there must be some $N > a_n$ such that none of the products with an already chosen $a_i$ is a square. That must be true since you could always take $N$ to be a prime, but you don't need anything about primes to find $N$. Just start testing with $N = a_n +1, a_n + 2, \ldots$ until you get an $N$ that works. Use that $n$ for $a_{n+1}$.

(This is not an efficient algorithm!)